# whats wrong with this switch $_GET error?

Tags: php

```
<?php switch (true) :
    case $_GET['change']:
      echo 'hello';
    break;
    default:
      echo 'bye';
    break; ?>
```

It gives me this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\profile.php on line 47.

And that is the end of my code.
What did i forgot because if I comment this piece of code it works well.

Comment: Learn how to use it http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: you can not put $_GET['change'] as case

Comment: agree with @jitendrapurohit

Comment: If you are only dealing with two condition options, switch is overkill.  Just use a simple if/else statement.  Or do you have more code that you aren't showing.

Comment: If you need to check if `$_GET['change']==true` you are out of luck as `$_GET` parameters are either strings or not set at all and a non-empty string is always `== true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
<?php 
    switch (true) :
        case $_GET['change']:
            echo 'hello';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'bye';
            break; 
    endswitch;
?>
```

It is because you miss endswitch; or just use brackets {}

Comment: One more question, is this the right url http://localhost/profile.php?change??

Comment: It is valid url, but if its correct I don't know, if the page /profile.php exists then yes it is right url, ?change is the $_GET parameter. You can use it like that ?change=yourValue

Answer (score 3):

Your switch case need a variable to handle the `case` like:

```
<?php
switch($_GET["change"])
{
   case "value":
     echo "You called this case.";
     break; // Stop the switch for being executing futher.

   default:  // Set default message if the case wasn't found.
     echo "Cannot find the case.";
     break;

}
?>
```

Read more: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Answer (score 2):

You're using the alternative syntax for control-structures, which means you have to close your switch at the end, with this

```
endswitch
```

making your full code

```
switch (true):
    case $_GET['change']:
        echo 'hello';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'bye';
        break; 
endswitch;
?>
```

---

Although, you can simplify this piece of code to the following, unless you intend to expand your `switch/case` structure.

```
echo isset($_GET['change']) ? "hello" : "bye";
```

In any case, just doing `case $_GET['change']:` just checks if that holds any values, not what they are, or if its set at all, so you may get warnings about this. If you intend to expand your structures, you should see the example of @C0dekid - that's how you should build your `switch/case`

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Answer (score 1):

It should be as following:

```
<?php 
switch ($_GET['change']) {
case [YOURVALUEHERE]:
  echo 'hello';
break;
default:
  echo 'bye';
break; 
}
?>
```

Example from [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i equals 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "i equals 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "i equals 2";
        break;
    default:
       echo "i is not equal to 0, 1 or 2";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better to set brackets:

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['change']) {
    case true:
        echo 'hello';
    break;
    default:
        echo 'bye';
    break;
}
?>
```

If you want to use the [alternate syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) take a look at this warning:

> **Warning**
>
> Any output (including whitespace) between a switch statement and the first case will result in a syntax error. For example, this is invalid:

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put right enclosure for your switch, dont use ":" but "{". For example:

```
switch (true) {
case $_GET['change']:
  echo 'hello';
break;
default:
  echo 'bye';
break;
}
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php.

Comment: Yea offcourse, he forgot endswitch... But shouldn't these questions be deleted?

Comment: Yes, but with 6 answers cant be deleted now.